# Optimally partitioning the reciprocals of the first n integers

Tags: algorithms, partitions

Do we know anything about the hardness of the optimization version of the [multiway number partitioning problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) when the set of numbers to partition consists of the reciprocals of the first $n$ integers? That is, for $n, k\in \mathbb{N}$, find sets $S_1,\dots,S_k$ such that

- $\bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i = \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}\}$,
- $S_i \cap S_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$

that minimizes the largest difference between two sets, i.e., that minimizes $\max_{i,j}| \sum_{x \in S_i} x - \sum_{y \in S_j} y|$.

I am curious about other objective functions too. I am mainly interested about the effect of restricting the set of numbers to partition.

Comment: Could you please clarify, if $S_i$ is a set or a multi-set?

Comment: $S_i \ \subseteq \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}\}$ is a simple set.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all elements is H_n (n-th harmonic number), approximately ln n + c where ln is the natural logarithm and c is quite small.

If k > H_n then the average size of a set is less than 1. So take {1} as the first set and you have H_n - 1 and k-1 sets left. If the average is > 1/2 then you take the set {1/2} etc until you have enough left for the sets. At that point it’s quite similar to bin packing, except the problem isn’t “how many bins of size s are needed” but “what is the smallest s so that k bins all contain more than s”.

Now if you were given n numbers then the problem size would be O(n) and the problem would be NP-complete. But the problem is given by two numbers, so the problem size is just log n + log k, so it’s much much harder relative to the problem size.